# Difference between aggregate and table functions

Tags: r

```
Age <- c(90,56,51,64,67,59,51,55,48,50,43,57,44,55,60,39,62,66,49,61,58,55,45,47,54,56,52,54,50,62,48,52,50,65,59,68,55,78,62,56)

Tenure <- c(2,2,3,4,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,4,3,2,4,1,3,4,2,2,4,3,4,1,2,2,3,3,1,3,4,3,2,2,2,2,3,1,1)

df <- data.frame(Age, Tenure)
```

I'm trying to count the unique values of `Tenure`, thus I've used the `table()` function to look  at the frequencies

```
table(df$Tenure)

1  2  3  4 
5 15 13  7
```

However I'm curious to know what the `aggregate()` function is showing?

```
aggregate(Age~Tenure , df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

Tenure Age
1      1   3
2      2  13
3      3  11
4      4   7
```

**What's the difference between these two outputs?**

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the difference is your inclusion of `unique` in the `aggregate`.  You are counting the number of distinct Ages by Tenure, not the count of Ages by Tenure. To get the analogous output with `aggregate` try

```
aggregate(Age~Tenure , df, length)
  Tenure Age
1      1   5
2      2  15
3      3  13
4      4   7
```

Comment: Or just `aggregate(Age~Tenure , df, length)`

Comment: @G5W we meet again. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are a lot of "regulars" I hope that the answer helped